# Matlab Save() & Load() methods to python equivalent

Tags: python, matlab

I'm new to Python and I'm needing to convert some Matlab code I have to Python.  Here's the code I have:

```
    save(myFile, 'list','config');
else
    load(myfile, 'list');
end
```

I've been looking within Python and I can't seem to find an equivalent method for this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can also look up pickling, python's object serialization: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the numpy IO routines [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html), they can handle various formats.